# How to disable username change in Djoser?

Tags: django, djoser

I haven't found any information in documentation about how to exclude/disable any of the endpoints provided by Djoser. I could just look for one in it's urlpatterns and remove it but I'm wondering if there's any less ugly way to do that.

Comment: Right now it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom view that returns an error code and provide it in your own `urls.py` before you include djoser's URLs, to pre-empt access to specific endpoints.

It's not as ideal as having settings to support this, but until/unless the app supports this, overriding its URLs with your own is a way to do what you're asking without having to maintain a modified local version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution. Instead of using `include("djoser.urls.base")`, do something like so:

```py
from djoser.views import UserViewSet

# Taken from Djoser's source
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"users", UserViewSet, basename="users")

def is_route_selected(url_pattern):
    urls = [
        "usuarios/set_email/",
        "usuarios/reset_email_confirm/",
    ]

    for u in urls:
        match = url_pattern.resolve(u)
        if match:
            return False
    return True

# Filter router URLs removing unwanted ones
selected_user_routes = list(filter(is_route_selected, router.urls))

# Of course, instead of [] you'd have other URLs from your app here:
urlpatterns = [] + selected_user_routes
```